# Get Diffgram data Web Service Client Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I make a webservice client in Java.

When i make the request:

```
PROCESARECARGAResult result = port.procesaRECARGA(claroDoLoadCashBean.getPhone(), stringDate,
                claroDoLoadCashBean.getAmount(), claroDoLoadCashBean.getTransactionId(),
                claroDoLoadCashBean.getPaymentCode(), claroDoLoadCashBean.getSignalStatus(),
                claroDoLoadCashBean.getChannelCode(), username, password);
```

In the dump, show me the request and the response, however the variable `result` is null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<PROCESA_RECARGAResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <PROCESA_RECARGAResult>
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Table1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Codigo_Respuesta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="Descripcion_Respuesta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                <Codigo_Respuesta>001</Codigo_Respuesta>
                <Descripcion_Respuesta>Usuario no tiene permiso para realizar transacciones</Descripcion_Respuesta>
            </Table1>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
    </PROCESA_RECARGAResult>
</PROCESA_RECARGAResponse>
```

There is way to get the `<diffgr:diffgram` data?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848382/how-to-unmarshall-xml-code-containing-xmlanyelement-and-diffgr) is a similar question in where seems to happen the same thing. But without response :(

Thanks!